# Capsule making?

Tags: woodworking, fiber-crafts

Is it possible make letter capsules in wood or fabric? I just ordered some plastic versions of this item from amazon.com and was just wondering if it was a possible to make them myself.￼
These are basically pill shaped items to contain small letters to give to people you care about.
If it’s possible to make these then I figured that it would make great Christmas/birthday gifts!
￼

Comment: It would help if you explained how letter capsules look and work so the people who want to answer your question don't have to research it before answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Write out your messages on paper and then cut it out.
- Roll it up into a scroll.
- Take the height of the scroll and add about 3/4 of an inch to determine the length of drinking straw that you need.
- Cut a drinking straw to that length.
- Light a candle and after it has burned for a minute or two, dump some of the liquid wax onto a heat resistant surface.
- Before the wax solidifies, stick one end of the cut straw into it so that the hardening wax fills and corks one end of the straw.  Clean off any excess wax from the exterior of the straw.
- Put the scroll into the open end of the straw then tie it closed with some thread or thin ribbon using a slip knot or bow for ready reopening.
- Paint or decorate your finished capsule